# Can $|\Psi\rangle\simeq\sum_k |u_k\rangle|v_k\rangle$ be maximally entangled even if $\{|u_k\rangle\}_k,\{|v_k\rangle\}_k$ are not orthonormal?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

Let $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle}\{\ket{u_k}\}_k,\{\ket{v_k}\}_k\subset\mathcal H$ be orthonormal bases in an $N$-dimensional space. It then follows that the state
$$\ket\Psi = C\sum_{k=1}^N \ket{u_k}\otimes\ket{v_k}\tag1$$
is maximally entangled (where $C$ is a normalisation constant).
Or more generally, it means that $|\Psi\rangle$ has rank $N$ (which if the embedding space is larger does not correspond to a maximally entangled state).

Does the opposite direction hold? In other words, if we know that a state $\ket\Psi$ is maximally entangled and can be written as (1), can we conclude that $\langle u_j|u_k\rangle=\langle v_j|v_k\rangle=\delta_{jk}$?
Equivalently, suppose $\ket\Psi$ has the form in (1) with $\{\ket{u_k}\}_k,\{\ket{v_k}\}_k$ *not* orthogonal. Can $\ket\Psi$ then be maximally entangled?

More generally, suppose $\dim\mathcal H=M$ with $M>N$ (the vectors are not a basis). If $|\Psi\rangle$ is as in (1), can it have rank $N$ even if $\{\ket{u_k}\}_k,\{\ket{v_k}\}_k$ are not orthogonal?

For example, in the simplest case with $M=2$ and $N>M$, the question is whether a state of the form
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+\Re[\langle u_1|u_2\rangle\langle v_1|v_2\rangle])}} \left(\ket{u_1}\otimes\ket{v_1}+\ket{u_2}\otimes\ket{v_2}\right)$$
can be maximally entangled (or more precisely, have Schmidt coefficients $(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2,0,...,0)$) even if $\langle u_1|u_2\rangle,\langle v_1|v_2\rangle\neq0$.

---

I'll show here that it is crucial that *both* bases are non-orthogonal for this to be possible.

If only one of the two sets, say $\{\ket{v_k}\}_k$, is orthonormal, then the matrix of coefficients of $\ket\Psi$, write it with $\Psi$, has the form $\Psi = U \sqrt D V^T$, where $U,V$ are the matrices whose columns equal $\ket{u_k}$ and $\ket{v_k}$, respectively, and $D$ is diagonal. The orthonormality of $\{\ket{v_k}\}_k$ (and thus of $\{\ket{\bar v_k}\}_k$) then implies that
$$\Psi\Psi^\dagger = UDU^\dagger,$$
which tells us that the Schmidt coefficients of $\ket\Psi$ majorize the diagonal of $\sqrt{D}$. E.g. if $D$ is a multiple of the identity then $\Psi\Psi^\dagger \simeq UU^\dagger\neq I$, and thus $\ket\Psi$ is *not* maximally entangled.

This would seem to suggest that, if at least one of the bases is orthonormal, then indeed $\ket\Psi$ is maximally entangled only if the other basis is also orthonormal.
But this still leaves open the possibility of it being possible when both bases are not orthonormal.

---

Here is an example of a pair of non-orthogonal states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ such that $|\psi\psi\rangle+|\phi\phi\rangle$ has rank 2. Define
\begin{align}
2\sqrt2 \ket\psi &= \ket1 + (2+i)\ket2 - \ket3 + i \ket4, \\
2\sqrt2 \ket\phi &= \ket1 + i\ket2 + (1-2i)\ket3 - i \ket4.
\end{align}
Let $\ket\Psi\equiv (\ket{\psi\psi}+\ket{\phi\phi})/\sqrt{3/2}$.
You can then verify that the corresponding matrix of coefficients is
$$C = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1+i & -i & 0 \\
  1+i & 1+2 i & 0 & i \\
  -i & 0 & -1-2 i & -1-i \\
  0 & i & -1-i & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
As can be readily checked, the only non-vanishing eigenvalue of $C^\dagger C$ is a two-fold degenerate $+1/2$, hence $\ket\Psi$ has rank $2$.

It's possible that this is only possible because the states live in a larger space, *i.e.* $M=4$ but $N=2$. I'm wondering if there is a good way to understand why this can happen, and if it possible also when $N=M$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my surprise, your statement is not true. Consider the qubit example:
$$
|\Psi\rangle=|00\rangle-|++\rangle.
$$
This is clearly of the correct form but with non-orthogonal states (in case you're worrying about the negative sign, we put $|u_2\rangle=|+\rangle$ and $|v_2\rangle=-|+\rangle$). However, it is maximally entangled. To see this, we expand it out:
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\frac12\left(|00\rangle-|01\rangle-|10\rangle-|11\rangle\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0-\rangle+|1+\rangle),
$$
which is equivalent under local unitaries (Hadamard on the second qubit) to the Bell state, and hence maximally entangled.

Comment: ah! $|00\rangle+|++\rangle$ was actually the first state I tried this on, and it didn't work. I didn't think a simple sign change would make a difference in this context. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts; I am not $100\%$ sure yet and will revisit:

A bi-partite (pure) state $|\Psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_{A} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{B}$ is *maximally entangled* if the reduced state in either $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ or $\mathcal{H}_{B}$ is the maximally mixed state.

Suppose we have a state
\begin{equation}
|\hat{\Psi}\rangle = C \sum_{k=1}^{N}|u_{k}\rangle \otimes |v_{k}\rangle,
\end{equation}
where  $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ may or may not be orthonormal. Lets assume that they are at least normalized.

Furthermore, let $\{|a_{j}\rangle\}$ be an *orthonormal* basis for $\mathcal{H}_{A}$.
The reduced state $\rho_{B} = \mathrm{tr}_{A}\big[|\hat{\Psi}\rangle\langle \hat{\Psi}|\big]$ on $\mathcal{H}_{B}$ is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho_{B} &= \sum_{j} \big(\langle{a_{j}}|\otimes I \big) |\hat{\Psi}\rangle\langle \hat{\Psi}| \big(|{a_{j}}\rangle\otimes I \big) \\
&= |C|^{2}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}\sum_{k'} \langle a_{j}|u_{k}\rangle \langle u_{k'}|a_{j}\rangle \otimes |v_{k}\rangle\langle v_{k'}| \\
&= |C|^{2}\sum_{k}\sum_{k'} \langle u_{k'}| \Big( \sum_{j}| a_{j}\rangle\langle a_{j} |\Big) |u_{k}\rangle   |v_{k}\rangle\langle v_{k'}| \\
&= |C|^{2}\sum_{k}\sum_{k'}  \langle u_{k'}| I |u_{k}\rangle  |v_{k}\rangle\langle v_{k'}|. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If we put the $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ in matrices $U$ and $V$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U &= \begin{bmatrix}|u_{1}\rangle & |u_{2}\rangle \cdots |u_{n}\rangle\end{bmatrix} \\
V &= \begin{bmatrix}|v_{1}\rangle & |v_{2}\rangle \cdots |v_{n}\rangle\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
we get for:
\begin{equation}
U^{\dagger}U = \begin{bmatrix} \langle u_{1}|u_{1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle u_{1}|u_{n}\rangle \\ . & \ddots & . \\ 
\langle u_{n}|u_{1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle u_{n}|u_{n}\rangle \\\end{bmatrix} = I + \hat{D}_{U}
\end{equation}
for some off-diagonal (Hermitian, likely sparse) matrix $\hat{D}_{U}$. We can do the same for $V$, getting $\hat{D}_{V}$

That allows us to write for $\rho_{B}$:

\begin{split}
\rho_{B} &= |C|^{2}\sum_{k}\sum_{k'}  \langle u_{k'} |u_{k}\rangle  |v_{k}\rangle\langle v_{k'}|\\
&= |C|^{2}\sum_{k}\sum_{k'}    |v_{k}\rangle \langle u_{k'} |u_{k}\rangle \langle v_{k'}|\\
&=   |C|^{2}VU^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger} \\
\end{split}

The question is now when this is or is not equal to the maximally mixed state i.e. $|C|I$ (note that the normalisation factor is different because we're in a smaller space!). We know, since $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ are in fact bases, both $U$ and $V$ are invertible, such that $\rho_{B} = |C|^{2}VU^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}= |C|I$ implies that:
\begin{equation}
U^{\dagger} U = V^{-1} (V^{\dagger})^{-1} = (V^{\dagger}V)^{-1}
\end{equation}
up to some normalisation factor.
Lets investigate the three (without loss of generality) options:

- The bases $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ are orthonormal.
  Then, $U^{\dagger}U = V^{\dagger}V = I$ and the state is maximally entangled, as expected.
- $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ is, but $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ isn't orthonormal.
  Then, $U^{\dagger}U = I \not = V^{\dagger}V$. This shows that if only *one* of the bases is orthonormal, the state cannot be maximally entangled.
- Both $\{|u_{k}\rangle\}$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ aren't orthonormal. Then, $U^{\dagger}U,V^{\dagger}V \not = I $. The state might still be maximally entangled, as long as $U^{\dagger}U$ is the inverse of $V^{\dagger}V$, or in other words: $|C|U^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}V = I$.
  We can say a little more:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  I &= |C|U^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}V\\
  &= |C|(I + \hat{D}_{U})(I + \hat{D}_{V}) \\
  &= |C|I +  |C|\hat{D}_{U} + |C|\hat{D}_{V} + |C|\hat{D}_{U}\hat{D}_{V} \\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  Both $\hat{D}_{U}$ and $\hat{D}_{V}$ are purely anti-diagonal, which means that their product $\hat{D}_{U}\hat{D}_{V}$ has diagonal elements that are equal to $1-|C|$. The off-diagonal terms need to cancel out; in higher dimensions this could get messy.

### Some extra thoughts about the bi-partite case

For a bi-partite state (and thus $\hat{D}_{U}\hat{D}_{V}$ purely diagonal) we get that $\hat{D}_{U} = -\hat{D}_{V}$, which means that

$$\langle u_{1}|u_{2}\rangle = - \langle v_{1}|v_{2}\rangle.$$

Moreover, for the bi-partite state we also get $\frac{1}{2}I = I + \hat{D}_{U}\hat{D}_{V}$ so that

$\hat{D}_{U}\hat{D}_{V} = -\frac{1}{2}I$ which leads to
$$\langle u_{1}|u_{2}\rangle \langle v_{2}|v_{1}\rangle = \langle u_{2}|u_{1}\rangle \langle v_{1}|v_{2}\rangle = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

You can combine this to say that $\langle v_{1}|v_{2}\rangle\langle v_{2}|v_{1}\rangle = \langle u_{1}|u_{2}\rangle\langle u_{2}|u_{1}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}$. This puts quite strong constraints on the bases.
Essentially, the bases provided by [Daftwullies answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13964/8141) seem to be (up to permutations and some extra phases) the only ones.

### An example after [Daftwullies answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13964/8141)

The relation $U^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}V = I$ can very well be met even if $U$ and $V$ are not unitary; we have (for the bases Daftwullie came up with):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U &= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
V &= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & -1 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which can be readily checked to obey $U^{\dagger}U V^{\dagger}V = I$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}V &= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & -1 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 2
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -\sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 2
\end{bmatrix}  \\
&\sim I
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The states also obey the above equations for the inner products in the bi-partite case.

### Old incorrect analysis

Now I first wrote the text below, but this is actually incorrect. After the [answer of DaftWullie](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13964/8141) it became clear that there actually *are* examples of this. My error in the below derivation is that the Frobenius inner product $2\langle VV^{\dagger}, V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}\rangle$ does **not** bear a square, and can therefore be negative. That means that the inequality actually does not hold.

> I don't actually think that this is possible under the assumption that
> all states need to be normalized. (which means, if you recall, that
> $U^{\dagger}U = I + \hat{D}_{U}$ with that identity being, well, the
> identity).
>
> We already had $U^{\dagger}U = I + \hat{D}_{U}$, so that (using the
> [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)): $$||U^{\dagger}U||^{2} = ||I + \hat{D}_{U}||^{2}  =||I||^{2} + ||\hat{D}_{U}||^{2} + 2\langle I,\hat{D}_{U}\rangle_{F} = ||I||^{2} + ||\hat{D}_{U}||^{2} \geq ||I||^{2},$$ where $\langle I, \hat{D}_{U}\rangle_{F}$ is the Frobenius inner product, which is zero
> here because $\hat{D}_{U}$ is by definition traceless. Moreover, the
> inequality becomes strict when $\hat{D}_{U}$ is non-empty and
> therefore $||\hat{D}_{U}|| > 0$ (the Frobenius norm *is* a norm). This
> is only true if the basis encoded in $U$ is non-orthogonal.
>
> For our relation $\rho_{B} = I = VU^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger} = V(I +
> > \hat{D}_{U})V^{\dagger} = VV^{\dagger} + V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}$, we
> get:
>
> \begin{equation} \begin{split} ||I||^{2} &= ||VU^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger}||^{2} = ||VV^{\dagger} + V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} \\ &= ||VV^{\dagger}||^{2} + ||V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} + 2\langle VV^{\dagger},V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}\rangle \\ &\geq ||VV^{\dagger}||^{2} +
>  ||V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} \\ & = ||I ||^{2} + ||
>  \hat{D}_{V}||^{2} + ||V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} \\ & \geq ||I
>  ||^{2} + ||V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} \\ \end{split} \end{equation}
>
> with the second bound only an equality if $||\hat{D}_{V}|| = 0$, which
> is **not** the case if the basis encoded in $V$ is not orthogonal. So
> in that case we have $||I||^{2} \geq ||I||^{2} + || \hat{D}_{V}||^{2}
> > + ||V\hat{D}_{U}V^{\dagger}||^{2} > ||I||^{2}$, which is a contradiction. We have to conclude that $\hat{D}_{V}$, and conversely
> $\hat{D}_{U}$ are zero, which means that the bases must be orthogonal.

Comment: The completeness relation on the $\{|u_j\rangle\}$ only holds if it's an orthonormal basis, which we are explicitly excluding here, surely?

Comment: @DaftWullie I think you 're right. I've closed my answer for now.

Comment: @DaftWullie I changed the basis over which the trace is performed to some orthonormal basis $\{|a_{j}\rangle\}$ so that the completeness relation holds.

Comment: the trace in the middle of the expression is acting on a scalar, so it seems quite superfluous. That aside, if I understand you, you are showing that the partial trace *does not equal* $\sum_k |v_k\rangle\!\langle v_k|$. But what is this telling you? The $|v_k\rangle$ are not necessarily orthogonal either, so you are not showing that the partial trace is not (proportional to) the identity

Comment: The trace is more or less unnecessary, but it does add a little more clout to re-arranging the inner products so that it 'becomes' and operator.

Also, I was working under the assumption that $\{|v_{k}\rangle\}$ actually is an orthonormal basis. Then this shows that the partial trace becomes something which is not (proportional to) the identity, and therefore that the bi-partitie state can _not_ be a maximally entangled state.

Comment: If you also include non-orthonormality of $|v_{k}\rangle$, the argument becomes more intricate.

Comment: to be honest the trace seems like a miscalculation there. I'm not sure where it even comes from. You already effectively took the trace by applying $|a_j\rangle$ left and right and summing. I agree with the argument that if one of the bases is orthogonal then the other must be. I also added an argument in this direction in the question, see edit. But this leaves the case of both bases not being orthonormal. Indeed, I'm almost certain you *can* have a maximally entangled state of the form $|\psi\psi\rangle+|\phi\phi\rangle$ with $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\neq0$. I'll try to add an example later

Comment: @glS I have done some extensive re-editing, but I'm not 100% sure of the answer yet. I provide it for discussion, but please use with caution.

Comment: @glS Indeed you can, see the example I just added.

Comment: @DaftWullie You are right, thanks. I actually made an error in the analysis which I explained above. I quickly also calculated the $U$ and $V$ for your bases, which indeed do obey the correct eq. $VU^{\dagger}UV^{\dagger} = I$.